# Instagram Graph API Returning "error_message"=>"Invalid platform app"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Im trying to get authenticate with Instagram Graph API. When I do the following with a curl command it returns my `access_token`.

When I use HTTParty gem, Instagram Graph API returns the following:

```
[22] pry(InstagramService)* )
=> {"error_type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>400, "error_message"=>"Invalid platform app"}
```

I really tried but I can't see what im doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
class InstagramService
  def self.get_access_token(code)
    token_params = {
      client_id: ENV['INSTAGRAM_APP_ID'],
      client_secret: ENV['INSTAGRAM_APP_SECRET'],
      grant_type: "athorization_code",
      redirect_uri: ENV['INSTAGRAM_OAUTH_REDIRECT_URL'],
      code: code # <-- This is the code sent by Instagram API. Used to get access token.
    }

    request = HTTParty.post(
      "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token", 
      body: token_params.to_json,
      headers:  { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
    )
  end
end
```

**Does anyone know whats wrong? Why am I getting this error instead of the `access_token`, the same that I get when I use the curl command.**

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \
  -F client_id=684477648739411 \
  -F client_secret=eb8c7... \
  -F grant_type=authorization_code \
  -F redirect_uri=https://socialsizzle.herokuapp.com/auth/ \
  -F code=AQDp3TtBQQ...
```

Comment: There is a typo at grant_type: "athorization_code". Should be authorization_code, not sure if that causes the issue however.